# checking for cycles in a directed graph haskell

Tags: haskell

I have created a directed graph in Haskell. I would like to write an algorithm that checks the graph for cycles. Are there library functions available that could do this quickly?

Comment: There are probably library functions you can use as _part_ of your solution, but if you have designed your graph representation yourself, there's no reason to expect any library function to work on exactly that representation of graphs.

Answer (score 4):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl is fairly complete, and I have heard it's speedy as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [containers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.1.0), [`Data.Graph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Graph.html) includes functions for [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) (which are essentially cycles).